# Magento validation and jQuery reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

i got this weird issue on happening only on IE8, 9, 10 and 11.

I wrote some jQuery validation code for telephone field on "`admin/sales_order_create/index`". This code worked as expected on Firefox. But on The IE it doesnt work until I refresh the page.

The jQuery seems to stop or conflict with the prototype, and that cause the prototype not load/ other js functions not to load.

here is my inline jQuery code loaded on `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/form/renerer/fieldset.phtml` (it doesn't work even if I load as an external file).

how can I make this work on all IE or reload the page without manually reload the `admin/sales_order_create/index`, or add classes on the form in `admin/sales_order_create/index`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        <!--Enforce maximum of 15 characters-->
        jQuery("#order-billing_address_telephone").attr('maxlength','15');

        <!--ids we will be listening for when change takes place-->
        jQuery( "#_item1telephone, #order-billing_address_telephone" ).change(function() {
            <!--if the length on the number is morethan 15 characters, then alert and disable buttons-->
            if(jQuery(this).val().length > 15 ){
                jQuery('.save').addClass("disable");
                alert("Please do not enter more than 15 Telephone numbers. Adding more will results to failure of orders!");
            }
            else if(jQuery(this).val().length <= 15){
                jQuery(".save").attr("class","save");
            }
            <!--alphanumeric are not allowed on telephone-->
            if(!jQuery.isNumeric(jQuery(this).val()) ){
                jQuery('.save').addClass("disable");
                alert("Please use numbers only. Letters and spaces are not allowed.");
            }

    });
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think this is breaking the script, but just to note that you're using HTML comments inside your Javascript... Comments should be
/* comment here */

Comment: wow! you're correct the problem were the html comments.. it's working now thank you :)